# Looping through ArrayList to get an item number

Tags: java, loops, arraylist, get

the error is not returning the desired statement so I need the thiung to output a positive integer that will be able to duplicate an array list, this would be much appreciate thatnks

```
@Override
public String getDescription(int itemNumber)    {
    if(isKnownItemNumber(itemNumber) == true)   {
        for (recordItem i : itemList)    {
            if(i.getItemNumber() == itemNumber)    {
                return description;
            }
        }
    }
    return "does not exist";
}

   @Override
public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}
```

And here is the main method with the populated arraylist:

```
package Purchase;
import java.util.*;

import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()   {


        public void run() {
            gui.PosGUI.makeAndShowGUI();


            Items.newItems.recordItem(01,"banana",1.00,1);
            , "Mayonnaise", 2.00, 0);



        }

    });

}
}
```

Comment: Why getItemNumber function takes parameter?? it should return the itemNumber of item, you are passing one parameter to the function and returning same parameter..\

Comment: and what is the recordItem ??

Comment: Anoops first comment marked your mistake. Try it without parameters or return this.itemNumber; Allthough looking at your code you should have only bananas in your Itemlist. By the way better change `isItemNumber(...)==false` to `!isItemNumber(...)`. Does the same, but looks better.

Comment: @AnoopLL alright ive made those changes (edited above) but now it just returns 'does not exist'.

Comment: It's because you only record to your static item :-). So only the latest record will be saved (and a lot of new Items (empty) in your list).

Answer (score 1):

The usual contract of a *getter* method is to take no parameters, and return the asked field.

Your `getItemNumber` method takes a parameter, and returns it as a result, this makes no sense.

```
public int getItemNumber(int itemNumber) {
    return itemNumber;
}
```

Replace this method with a common getter :

```
public int getItemNumber() {
        return itemNumber;
    }
```

And your `isKnownItemNumber` method becomes :

```
public boolean isKnownItemNumber(int itemNumber)    {

    //assert itemNumber >= 0 : "Item Number must be greater than or equal to 0";
    for (recordItem i : itemList)    {
        if (i.getItemNumber() == itemNumber)   {
            return true;
        }

    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: alright ive made those changes (edited above) but now it just returns 'does not exist'.

Comment: This must not be the full error message, what does not exist ?

Comment: well in getDescription if it doest find the item with that number it returns 'does not exist'

Comment: Oh yes sorry I missed that message.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably another mistake in your record-Method. You set the arguments on this, not on the new Item you create. Try this instead:

```
@Override
public void recordItem(int itemNumber, String description, double unitPrice, int sort)  {

   if ((isKnownItemNumber(itemNumber) == false) && (unitPrice > 0) && (sort == 0 || sort == 1)) {
       Items theItems = new Items();
       theItems.itemNumber = itemNumber;
       theItems.description = description;
       theItems.unitPrice = unitPrice;
       theItems.sort = sort;
       itemList.add(theItems);
   }

}
```

Another bug: the `return i.description;` instead of `return description;`

```
public String getDescription(int itemNumber)    {
    if(isKnownItemNumber(itemNumber) == true)   {
        for (recordItem i : itemList)    {
            if(i.getItemNumber() == itemNumber)    {
                return i.getDescription();
            }
        }
    }
    return "does not exist";
}

 public String getDescription(){
    return description;
}
```

Comment: that outputs null for some reason

Comment: Yeah, you should return i.description. :-). Else you return the description of your static Item, which is null. Look at edit.

Comment: it wont allow me to do i.description but allows me to do i.getdescription but that still returns 'does not exist'

Comment: add a normal getDescription(). Now it should work. I forgot you may have no access to your String description.